# Python: Read Line by Line to find regex and group within not working

Tags: python, regex

So I have a plaintext file and I want to use python to find all regex and make a list with all of the results.

This is what I tried with the interactive console:

```
>>> import re
>>> result = []
>>> file = open('guion.fountain')
>>> for line in file:
...     m = re.search("\[\[Prop\]\]\*(.*)\*", line)
...     result.append(m.group(1))
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

But I had no luck. It says something about the `m` variable being `NotType` instead of the result of the regexp search.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check with `if m:` before accessing `.group(1)`. Also, you most probably need to replace `.*` with `.*?`. If your expected match spans across lines, read the whole file in the memory, and use `re.DOTALL` modifier.

Comment: Can you share content or few lines of your file ?

Comment: Have you tried a simpler regex to see if that's the problem?

Comment: Looks like there is no group in m, e.g. it is finding no match (so it returns None, i.e. why it says NoneType, since None has type NoneType.  Look at that regex.  I agree with klutt. Try http://regexr.com/ for building a regex.  It will highlight what the regex matches.

Comment: Got it! With @WiktorStribiżew advice I have it working now. Thanks!

Comment: The `re.DOTALL` + lazy quantifier against all file worked?

Comment: I didn't used the re.DOTALL and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Trying reading the file line by line, using `with`, and open it for reading:

```
with open('guion.fountain', 'r') as file:
        result = []
        for line in file:
                m = re.search("\[\[Prop\]\]\*(.*)\*", line)
                result.append(m.group(1))
....
```

Answer (score 0):

If `re.search` fails to find a match, a `None` is returned. Thus, it is  a goode idea to check with `if m:` before accessing `m.group(1)`.

Also, you most probably need to read the whole file into memory since your matches span across multiple lines. Just replace `.*` with `.*?` and use `re.DOTALL` modifier when compiling the regex so as the `.` could match newline symbols.